# Kentor AuthServices: ClaimTypeNamespace for SessionIndex and LogoutNameIdentifier

Tags: kentor-authservices

As a service provider we are getting following claims from IDP (ADFS).

- http://kentor.se/AuthServices/LogoutNameIdentifier
- http://kentor.se/AuthServices/SessionIndex

In AuthServices codebase AuthServicesClaimTypes.ClaimTypeNamespace is set to http://kentor.se/AuthServices. Should this namespace reflect SP (https://mysite/AuthServices)?

Also, under identityProviders configuration section (web.config), I am not setting logoutUrl, but still I am getting LogoutNameIdentifier claim from Idp. We do not support single logout.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No, they should not reflect the namespace of your SP. The claim names are is using http://kentor.se to ensure they cannot collide with something else.
- It's a missing feature/bug that those claims are added even though you haven't configured single logout.

Comment: Thank you Anders for the clarification.