# SAML2 - SustainSys - Change the Root URI Of \LogoutNameIdentifier and \SessionIndex?

Tags: c#, owin, saml, sustainsys-saml2

i have successfully integrated the SAML sustainsys solution with the IdP initiated Service Provider Flow. (awesome tool, many thanks)

however, in the SAML response i am seeing the following claims:

http://Sustainsys.se/Saml2/LogoutNameIdentifier
http://Sustainsys.se/Saml2/SessionIndex

how can i / "should I" change these to the base URL of those SAML claims / endpoints?

maybe this answered my question: 
[Kentor AuthServices: ClaimTypeNamespace for SessionIndex and LogoutNameIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163052/kentor-authservices-claimtypenamespace-for-sessionindex-and-logoutnameidentifie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those claims are for keeping state to the logout process. The naming is chosen to guarantee they do not collide with anything else (by using a domain of mine). The format of those claims is non-documented and is subject to change.

So the short answer: Just let them be there. If you're not using logout you can safely remove them though.

Comment: thank you for answering, is there a spot in the docs where it shows how to do this from code? rather than through web.config? I started with the OWIN sample project

Comment: You can remove the claims in the AcsCommandResultCreated notification. But in normal cases you can just let them be there and ignore them.